# How to translate the "snooze" button on an alarm clock?

Tags: single-word-requests

The "snooze" button is a button we press when the alarm clock is ringing. In some alarm clocks, the button makes it ring again after 5/10 minutes. We could translate directly "snooze" to "dormeto", but I am not sure it is the correct way to do it. People usually don't use the button to nap, but to procrastinate in the morning. "Snooze" is also not very explicit on what the button does.

I am thinking of the word "Plipostigi", but I am sure stackexchange can provide me better alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

> Nuntempaj vekhorloĝoj havas **prokrastilon** por plu dormi kaj reaŭdigi la veksonon post kelkaj minutoj. https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vekhorlo%C4%9Do

Currently, alarm clocks have a **procrastinator tool** to sleep more, and to re-sound the wakeup sound after a few minutes.

Comment: I kind of though "A waiting button" could also be valid.  "Atendu"... This one is better.

Comment: *Prokrastilo* has a number of meanings, including "delay pedal" for music.